# In RingCentral webhook is there a way to differentiate different event filters?

Tags: php, webhooks, ringcentral

Like for example

If I want to listen to both

```
'eventFilters' => array(
                "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true&aggregate=true",
                "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store/instant?type=SMS"
```

Am I supposed to do a switch on every post request from RingCentral if I want to filter and analyze both events?

Say..

```
switch($eventid){
    case '/restapi/v1.0/account/<accountid>/extension/<extension>/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true&aggregate=true'
    //process data
    break;
}
```

But the webhook posts have different extensions to it. Is there an identifier of which event is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways I could think to solve the issue you've presented...

1. If you have a single subscription with multiple eventFilters on multiple extensions, as you've stated, filtering the incoming `webhook.event` URI and match the string for type is probably fastest, then route to a specific Notification Event Type handler.
2. You can create up to 20 Push Notification (Subscriptions) in your account, and each of those can hold upwards of 1000 eventFilters. You could create a separate webhook for any of the six (6) unique Notification Event Types you wish to monitor. Doing this would also allow you to [Update Subscriptions](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefUpdateSubscription) for extensions on-the-fly.
3. You could use duck-typing of the [NotificationType.body schema (https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#EventTypes.html) if you have only a single subscription registered which contains multiple Notification Event Types by checking if `webhook.body` has the required properties.

**Number 3 in PHP (untested code)**

```
$instantMessageEventTypeKeys = array('id', 'to', 'from', 'type', 'creationTime', 'lastModifiedTime', 'readStatus', 'priority', 'attachments', 'direction', 'availability', 'subject', 'messageStatus', 'conversationid');

function genericNotificationHandler($eventJson) {
  $eventObj = json_decode($eventJson, true);
  foreach($instantMessageEventTypeKeys) {
    // If the event.body keys match, route to 
    if(arrayKeys(eventObj=>['body']) === $instantMessageEventType)) {
      //Call some instantMessageSpecificEventHandler($eventObj);
    }
  }
}
```

**Number 3 in JavaScript (untested code)**

```
// Instant Message Notification Event Type properties
const instantMessageEventTypeKeys = ['id', 'to', 'from', 'type', 'creationTime', 'lastModifiedTime', 'readStatus', 'priority', 'attachments', 'direction', 'availability', 'subject', 'messageStatus', 'conversationid']

const proxyHandlers = {
  get (target, key) {
    if ('notificationEventType' === key[0]) {
      let targetKeys = target.body.ownKeys.sort().join(',');
      if(targetKeys === instantMessageEventTypeKeys.sort().join(',')) return 'Instant Message' 
    }
  }
}

const genericNotificationHandler = (notificationData) => {
  // You could create traps in handlers below to simplify further
  let pEvent = new Proxy(notificationData, proxyHandlers);
  if('Instant Message' === pEvent.notificationEventType) {
    // instantMessageSpecificEventHandler(notificationData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on Ben's first approach:

> If you have a single subscription with multiple eventFilters on multiple extensions, as you've stated, filtering the incoming `webhook.event` URI and match the string for type is probably fastest, then route to a specific Notification Event Type handler.

The webhook payload will look like the following. The `event` property will indicate the event type that is being triggered and your app can use that to initiate differentiated processing. I've used an empty `body` below, but in an actual post, it will be populated with a body specific to that event type.

```
{
    "uuid":"12345678901234567890",
    "event":"/restapi/v1.0/glip/posts",
    "timestamp":"2018-05-01T16:39:41.693Z",
    "subscriptionId":"11112222-3333-4444-5555-666677778888",
    "ownerId":"11111111",
    "body":{}
}
```

In the [Go community SDK `go-ringcentral`](https://github.com/grokify/go-ringcentral), I'm starting to build out a function that returns the event type, given the event string:

```
ParseEventTypeForFilter(eventFilter string) (EventType, error) {
```

Here's a list of event types:

```
const(
    AccountPresenceEvent EventType = iota
    ContactDirectoryEvent
    DetailedExtensionPresenceEvent
    DetailedExtensionPresenceWithSIPEvent
    ExtensionFavoritesEvent
    ExtensionFavoritesPresenceEvent
    ExtensionGrantListEvent
    ExtensionListEvent
    ExtensionInfoEvent
    ExtensionPresenceEvent
    ExtensionPresenceLineEvent
    GlipGroupsEvent
    GlipPostEvent
    GlipUnreadMessageCountEvent
    InboundMessageEvent
    IncomingCallEvent
    InstantMessageEvent
    MessageEvent
    MissedCallEvent
    RCVideoNotificationsEvent
    SubscriptionRenewalEvent
)
```

Code: https://github.com/grokify/go-ringcentral/blob/master/clientutil/event_filter.go